# How to modify a list recursively based on previous values assigned to it without using loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, recursion, dynamic

I have to write a code that needs to assign 0/1 to out based on matrix values. 
But 0/1 assignment is based on what it has assigned previously(last 2 assignments only).

The code explains the logic I am trying to achieve.

```
out = np.ones((1,dat_mat.shape[0]))[0]
for i in range(dat_mat.shape[0]):
    if i == 0 :
        out[i] = 1

    elif i == 1 :
        if ((dat_mat[i,0] >= dat_mat[i,1]) and (out[i-1] == 1 )):
            out[i] = 0
    else:
        if ((dat_mat[i,0] >= dat_mat[i,1]) and (out[i-1] == 1 )) or ((dat_mat[i,0] >= dat_mat[i,2]) and (out[i-2] == 1 )) :
            out[i] = 0
```

Sample of dat_mat is below -

```
Dat_Mat : 
col1 col2 col3
31   nan  nan
30   30   nan    
28   28   30
27   27   28
26   26   27
26   24   26
```

I need a output like this -

```
out
1
0
1
0
1
0
```

The order of data needs to be maintained.

I want to do it without using loops. As I need to run this on 35-45 rows of over a million sets.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please briefly describe the logic you are talking about?

Comment: The col1, col2 and column are populated on some logic. First row output is 1, then second row col1(30) is greater than or equal to col2 (30) and previous out is equal to 1. So now output for second row is 0. Third row onwards, col1, col2, col3 and values of out for last 2 rows plays a role is assigning the the current out value.

Comment: What if `col1` < `col2` ?

Comment: Then `out` is not modified. As you can see I have assigned all 1 in `out` before using `out = np.ones((1,dat_mat.shape[0]))[0]`. And later I am trying to assign 0 based on logic. Its just one of the way I was trying to do it.

Comment: The `else:` clause in your code can never execute - the preceeding `if` and `elif` cover all possible values that `i` can take.  Also, I think you mean `dat_mat[i-1]` instead of `dat_mat[i:1]` (and similar in several other places) - a slice makes no sense there.

Comment: I think I found the mistake. Made the changes. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `dat_mat[i][0]`, not `dat_mat[i:0]`.

Also you can use `out = np.ones(len(dat_mat))` instead of `out = np.ones((1,dat_mat.shape[0]))[0]`

Comment: Thank you! Will do that.